# Can .htaccess help me in this situation?

Tags: file, .htaccess

If a user goes to URL, say: http://www.domain.com/image/orange.jpg
but `orange.jpg` does not exist, however orange.png does, can .htaccess allow the user to find it?

Comment: NO; htaccess doesnot use list swith possible results for each request; why would you echo a invalid url and still want to find the right url?

Comment: Maybe enabling [Multiviews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) solves that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be possible. mod_rewrite allows to check for the existance of files. And it allows multiple passes of rewriting in case you do not stop that process actively using the `[L]` flag. .

So have a try with something like this as a starting point (untested):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/image/([^/.]).jpg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^/image/([^/.]).jpg /image/$1.png

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/image/([^/.]).png$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule - /image/no-found [G,L]
```

The above applies if defined inside the central server configuration (per-host configuration). For .htaccess style files the syntax is slightly different: the leading slash (`/`) inside the `RewriteRule` must not be present in that case. If you have a choice do the rewriting in the server configuration. .htaccess style files are something like a workaround and very error prone. Try to avoid them if possible.

Note however that such setup is somewhat limited and annoying to maintain. Often it is a better alternative to setup a small wrapper script (probably php based) that processes the request and check a number of alternatives before deciding what response to send. You could rewrite requests to something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/image/([^/.])\..+$ /image.php?name=%1
```

Now you can serve that request with a script `image.php` where you can check for existing versions of images without haste and return headers and content to your liking.

Comment: +1 for the idea. But maybe the 1st rule is changing the extension of the requested file when exists, not fetching another one with a different extension in case it does not exist. Not sure if that was your intention, though.

Comment: @faa Sorry, I don't get what you mean. The first rule intends to change the 'extension' from `.jpg` tp `.png` if the jpg variant does _not_ exist. This is as requested by the OP. Why shouldn't that png variant not be delivered then?

Comment: According to the rule, that `png` variant is delivered only if the requested file with the `jpg` extension exists. It is a positive condition what the rule requires `^/ whatever...` , where `whatever` must exist. Maybe you meant `!^/whatever...`

Comment: @faa Hm? Why that? I miss something... The first condition takes care only to apply the rule when actually a jpg is required. The second condition explicitly checks that the rule is only applied if the file does not exist (note the `!`, a negation). The rule itself does not check any file, it just performs string manipulation.

Comment: Completely agree. I was not implying the rule was wrong, I was just wondering why 2 identical matching conditions and assumed the first one was trying to validate the existence of the file, because the regex in the rewrite rule does the same (Removing the trailing slash, though). I just wanted to be sure about the intention of the first condition. But, it's perfectly clear.

Comment: @faa Ok, already wondered what I missed... In my eyes the two conditions are _not_ identical. The first on does not check for any existance, it is just validation the syntax of the requested 'path', so acts as a string function. It has nothing to do with the file system, physical or virtual. The existance of such a file would only be checked if the rewriting process would stop there, so if the request would be passed through to the handler. Which it is not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24264/discussion-between-arkascha-and-faa)

Comment: After an interesting discussion we agreed on the version above.